# Sunspot::Solr::Server::NotRunningError on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails

I am using sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
```

When I try to run a feature test I am getting the following error

```
server.rb:116:in `rescue in stop': Process with PID 38464 is no longer running (Sunspot::Solr::Server::NotRunningError)'
```

When I try to start Solr

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake sunspot:solr:start
```

I get the following error

```
Successfully started Solr ...
rake aborted!
Sunspot::Solr::Server::AlreadyRunningError: Server is already running with PID 38712
```

And then when I try to stop

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake sunspot:solr:stop
rake aborted!
Sunspot::Solr::Server::NotRunningError: Process with PID 38926 is no 
longer running
```